# Несколько цветовых гамм в приложении, чтобы пользователь мог выбрать

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте!
Имеется один layout, в нём несколько элементов. Нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог выбрать, какого цвета у него будет приложение, и в зависимости от того, что он выберет - менять цвет.
Непонятно, как реализовать. Допустим, он нажимает на кнопку - зеленый цвет, как поменять цвета элементов (только некоторых).

Comment: Хочу,  чтобы менялся цвет элементов в зависимости от выбранного пользователем цвета. Хочет в белых тонах - тогда эти элементы станут белыми, зеленый - зелеными

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например создать отдельный статический класс, в котором будет указан цвет интерфейса. С каким-то дефолтным значением.

На кнопку выбора цвета повесить слушатель, который будет менять поле в классе цвета.

При отрисовке экрана брать цвет из этого класса и рисовать им.